# Broken screen Galaxy s5, cannot unlock pattern

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, locked-out, broken-screen

My s5 has a screen damaged such that it displays properly, but does not respond to touch. How do I release the pattern lock to transfer my data to something else?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already looked into our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info)? There have been ump-teen people with the very same issue before you, so we've collected some first aid (from their questions and answers) there. If you cannot find a solution there that works for you, we need some more details – e.g. what Android version, whether USB-debugging is enabled, what you've already tried. PS: there's also our [locked-out tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be still able to enter recovery mode, if you have a modded recovery like TWRP or CWM you can recover your data as in that mode the phone is not locked by the system, therefore you can access photos, docs and so on, If however that is not the case, you can still install TWRP, if you had Debug mode on before the accident